# Implementing generic interface in not generic class

Tags: java, generics

I want to implements a generic interface in a class.
Consider implementing this generic interface:

```
public interface Lookup<T>{
  public T find(String name);
}
```

---

and this is the **not generic** class that implement Lookup:

```
public class IntegerLookup implements Lookup<Integer>{
  private Integer[] values;
  private String[] names;

  public IntegerLookup(String[] names, Integer[] values) {......}
  //now I want to write the implemented method - find
```

and my question is:
how do I need to write this implemented method?
I need to override it? yes?

```
public Object find(String name){...}
```

will be good? or:

```
public Integer find(String name){...}
```

Comment: Anywhere `T` is used in the super type, `Integer` should be used in the subclass that uses `Integer` as a type argument for `T`.

Comment: And why can't you just try it with an @Override annotation?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis but it was written Object not T in the super type... or I am getting wrong?

Comment: The super type, `Lookup`, has declared the method's return type as `T`.

Comment: Do you want a utility method that looks up strings but returns a flexible type based on how it's called?

Answer (score 3):

The syntax here

```
public class IntegerLookup implements Lookup<Integer>{
//                                           ^
```

binds the type argument provided, ie. `Integer`, to the type variable declared by `Lookup`, ie. `T`.

So,

```
public Integer find(String name){...}
```

This is the same as doing

```
Lookup<Integer> lookup = ...;
lookup.find("something"); // has a return type of Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

From your comments it sounds like you really want to use `Object` as the return type.  I can't imagine why you would want to do that, but if so, you actually need to implement `Lookup< Object >`, not `Lookup< Integer >`.

But don't do that.  Use `Integer` as the return type, since that type is standing in for `T` in your implementation.